# Can I change accommodation details mentioned in DS-160 if the initially selected hotel is unavailable during the interview?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I am in the process of applying for a US B1 visa, and in the DS-160 form I am required to provide the address where I will be staying. I plan to stay at a hotel, but I'm uncertain about its availability during my tentative interview date in August 2024, considering the event is scheduled for September 2024 in SFO. Although I can currently browse and add hotel details based on availability, I am unsure if the selected hotel will be available in August.

My question is: Can I modify the accommodation details during the visa interview if the initially mentioned hotel becomes unavailable by the time of the interview?